# How to split string if splitting character is dynamic or unknown?

Tags: java, string, split

I want to make a Java program in which I want to take a String as a input. The string will have two integer numbers and operation to be performed.
eg. 25+85
or 15*78

The output will the solution of the string.

But I don't know how to split the string because operator sign is not known before execution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138038/commandline-java-calculator

Comment: Split uses regular expressions, so simply `input.split("[+*\\-\\/]")` will cover the 4 basic operations.

Comment: Why not you use a javascript solution for that, java have javascript inside it, you can use the following code to evaluate a string for mathematical operations. 
----------
`ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
Object result = engine.eval("4*5");`

Comment: Surely, if he were willing to use a library, it would be easier to find a Java library that parses mathematical operations from strings, rather than running JavaScript code within a Java program in order to use a JS library.

Comment: @Dharmendra, will it always be exactly two numbers separated by one operator? Because that greatly simplifies the question.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to check what operation it is using by using `String.contains("+");` and checking all the other operators you want to support. Then split wherever that operator is, `String.split("+")`. From there parse the output of `String.split("+")` by using `Integer.parseInt(String s)` and then return the sum. Pretty simple, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` method of the String class to split the input at non-digit characters:

```
input.split("\\D");
```

This will give you an array containing only the numbers.
I guess you also want to get the operator somehow? Although it's not the most elegant way, you might want to start with `input.replaceAll("[^\\*\\+\\-\\/]", "")` to remove everything that's not an operator, but you will still have to do some careful input filtering. What if i type `5+4*6` oder `2+hello` ?